# How to merge two dataframe and assign NaN to missing values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe namely `df1` and `df2`. Both has around 30M rows so its pretty large.

The `df1` has 3 columns:
`A     B    C`     where `df2` has two columns `A D`.

The column `A` is mostly same but is unordered and has some values. For example `df2['A']` missing some values compare to `df1['A']`.

*what I need*

I need to merge two dataframe so that `df1` has column `D` but for those missing values, I need it to be `NaN`.

*Example*

`df1`

```
A B C
x 1 2
y 5 6
z 4 4
```

`df2`

```
A D
x 10
z 20
```

`Merged Dataframe`

```
A B C D
x 1 2 10
y 5 6 NaN
z 4 4 20
```

*What I have tried*

I tried using `df1.merge(df2, how='right', on="A")` but couldn't figure out how to make those missing values `NaN`. I also tried to iterate over the rows of `df2` and add the column `D` values to `df1` but it will take days to finish since the both dataframes are big.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it, just switch to a left merge so it keeps everything from df1 and fills from df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','y','z'], 'B':[1,5,4], 'C':[2,6,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','z'], 'D':[10,20]})
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='A')
```

Returns:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   x   1   2   10.0
1   y   5   6   NaN
2   z   4   4   20.0
```